# Django: Named Url's/ Same regex, different Names

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a `urls.py` file which contains multiple urls with same named paramaters and regex but different names. When I call a view function from the template using `{% url 'name' param %}` it calls the function which comes first in the `urls.py` file in disregard to the name. Here is the content of `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('accountsearch.views',
url(r'^$', 'account_search', name='account_search'),
url(r'(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$','reset_password',name='reset_password'),
url(r'(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$','reset_securityquestions',name='reset_securityquestions'),
```

I am  trying to call `reset_securityquestions` from the template using:

```
"{% url 'reset_securityquestions'   account.uuid user.uuid %}">
```

but it calls `reset_password` instead.

If I change the order of urls in `urls.py` to this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('accountsearch.views',
url(r'^$', 'account_search', name='account_search'),
url(r'(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$', 'reset_securityquestions',
    name='reset_securityquestions'),
url(r'(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$', 'reset_password', name='reset_password'),
```

and call `reset_password` using:

```
{% url 'reset_password' account.uuid user.uuid %}
```

it calls the `reset_security_questions` function. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django always take firsts matching url pattern , so rewrite the urls as :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('accountsearch.views',
   url(r'^$', 'account_search', name='account_search'),
   url(r'^reset-password/(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$','reset_password',name='reset_password'),
   url(r'^security-question/(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$','reset_securityquestions',name='reset_securityquestions'),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you are expecting Django to know which URL to use if they both have exactly the same url pattern. When the request comes in, all Django has to go on is the URL itself, and it will always try and match those in order. With your switched patterns, you'll find that the reset_password view now doesn't work.

You need to give Django some way of distinguishing between them. Usually some literal text, either as a prefix or a suffix, would be used, for example:

```
r'reset/(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$'
r'security/(?P<account_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(?P<user_uuid>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/$'
```

Comment: I am new to Django, I was thinking since I specified the names to the urls may be it can call the views using that. I guess I was wrong, it works fine now. Thank you.